# Is BTCFrog bitcoin QR code generator hacked?

Tags: qrcode

The following URL is self explanatory. It is trying to generate a QR code requesting 0.005BTC at the shown address

```
http://www.btcfrog.com/qr/bitcoinPNG3.php?address=31oLAAQDmuRAGfkviHPDXFgV15To4idott&size=200&label=xx&message=yy&amount=.005
```

This generates the QR code below

[image]

When this QR code is scanned with any wallet of your choice the receiving address switches to something else! The address is clearly owned by someone and has several transactions.

Is it hacked or I'm doing something seriously wrong?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, that’s the hacker’s BTC address. There are way too many fake BTC QR generators nowadays, so the best way to do that is to ask your wallet to generate the QR for you (or use a well-known website).

Comment: To add to that: avoid even searching for a bitcoin-specific QR generator, just use a general purpose one if you must. You're less likely to find scams that way.